# How to handle Android Fragments? Do you use a single project or 2 different projects

Tags: android, android-fragments, project

I am developing an android project, this projects uses fragments. As you know fragments are different in android SDK depending on version.

For API LEVEL >= 11 and API_LEVEL < 11 fragment usage and base libraries are very different. 
For API_LEVEL>= 11 an activity class supports fragment 
however For API_LEVEL <11 you need to use fragmentactivity class, which is derived from support library. 
So should I duplicate all activities ? Or should i create duplicate pacakages ? Or different projects ?

How can you solve this problem smart guys ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So should I duplicate all activities ?

No.

> Or so should i create duplicate pacakages ?

No.

> Or different projects ?

No.

> How can you solve this problem smart guys ?

Use `FragmentActivity` and the Android Support package. That implementation of fragments works from API Level 4 through API Level 17 (and, presumably, beyond).

Sometime in the future, when you drop support for API Level 10 and below, you can switch from `FragmentActivity` to `Activity` and update the rest of your imports (e.g., from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to `android.app.Fragment`).

Comment: So if I am publishing an application and if this application uses fragments it should implement FragmentActivity ,otherwise users using API_LEVEL <10 may not use this application. But is this useful ? Does fragmentactivity contains all capabilities of fragments.

Comment: @Yaya: "But is this useful ? " -- thousands of developers think so. "Does fragmentactivity contains all capabilities of fragments" -- generally speaking, yes.